# Python - how to do the same operation on multiple columns - calculate row with a previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'t':[0,1,2,3,4],'gr_A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'gr_B':[2,3,4,2,4], 'gr_C':[1,2,3,1,2],'gr_D':[5,3,2,5,2],
      'gr_E':[1,4,2,4,5],'gr_F':[7,4,2,1,5],'gr_G':[9,7,3,2,2]}
df1= pd.DataFrame(data)

df = [[0, 2,3,4,2,5,8,1]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['t','A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])

df= pd.merge(df1,df2, on='t', how='left')
df

   t  gr_A  gr_B  gr_C  gr_D  gr_E  gr_F  gr_G    A    B    C    D    E    F     G
0  0     1     2     1     5     1     7     9  2.0  3.0  4.0  2.0  5.0  8.0   1.0
1  1     2     3     2     3     4     4     7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  2     3     4     3     2     2     2     3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
3  3     4     2     1     5     4     1     2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
4  4     5     4     2     2     5     5     2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

to calculate future value of 'A', I use the formula A(t) = A(t-1)*(1+gr_A). and I do the same operation for all columns A, B, C, etc. (maybe 20+ columns) using the following code:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'A'] = df.loc[i-1, 'A'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_A'] )
    df.loc[i, 'B'] = df.loc[i-1, 'B'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_B'] )
    df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i-1, 'C'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_C'] )
    df.loc[i, 'D'] = df.loc[i-1, 'D'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_D'] )
    df.loc[i, 'E'] = df.loc[i-1, 'E'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_E'] )
    df.loc[i, 'F'] = df.loc[i-1, 'F'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_F'] )
    df.loc[i, 'G'] = df.loc[i-1, 'G'] * (1+df.loc[i, 'gr_G'] )
```

The output is:

```
   t  gr_A  gr_B  gr_C  gr_D  gr_E  gr_F  gr_G      A      B      C      D  \
0  0     1     2     1     5     1     7     9    2.0    3.0    4.0    2.0   
1  1     2     3     2     3     4     4     7    6.0   12.0   12.0    8.0   
2  2     3     4     3     2     2     2     3   24.0   60.0   48.0   24.0   
3  3     4     2     1     5     4     1     2  120.0  180.0   96.0  144.0   
4  4     5     4     2     2     5     5     2  720.0  900.0  288.0  432.0   

        E       F      G  
0     5.0     8.0    1.0  
1    25.0    40.0    8.0  
2    75.0   120.0   32.0  
3   375.0   240.0   96.0  
4  2250.0  1440.0  288.0
```

Although it works, the code looks quite tedious and I'm wondering is there an easier way for this. Thanks a lot for any suggestion and help.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way given you need the previous value of `A` for the formula to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the formula you are using to calculate future values and the name of the columns you can try with:

```
for i in 'ABCDEFG':
    df[i] = df.loc[0,i]*(1+df['gr_'+i].shift(-1)).cumprod().shift().fillna(df.loc[0,i])
```

Comment: Just test it for different cases, and it is exactly what I need. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks! This adds to the idea of knowing how the formula works it becomes a geometric progression, and therefore any value can be calculated with one formula

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create column pairs and take advantage of ffill to bring values into the same column:

```py
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    't': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'gr_A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_B': [2, 3, 4, 2, 4],
    'gr_C': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 'gr_D': [5, 3, 2, 5, 2],
    'gr_E': [1, 4, 2, 4, 5], 'gr_F': [7, 4, 2, 1, 5],
    'gr_G': [9, 7, 3, 2, 2]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8, 1]],
                   columns=['t', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='t', how='left')

# Save Original Column Order
orig_order = df.columns
# Get Interesting Columns From Each DataFrame
df1_cols = df1.columns[df1.columns != 't']
df2_cols = df2.columns[df2.columns != 't']
# Get Pairs
column_pairs = list(chain(*zip(df1_cols, df2_cols)))
# Put Pairs Next to each other and ffill
df = df[['t', *column_pairs]].ffill(axis=1)

# Add 1 To every Value After First Row
df.loc[1:, df2_cols] += 1
# Calculate Cumulative Product
df[df2_cols] = df[df2_cols].cumprod()
# Fix Column Order
df = df[orig_order]

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

`df`:

```
  t  gr_A  gr_B  gr_C  gr_D  gr_E  gr_F  gr_G     A     B     C     D      E      F     G
0.0   1.0   2.0   1.0   5.0   1.0   7.0   9.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   2.0    5.0    8.0   1.0
1.0   2.0   3.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   4.0   7.0   6.0  12.0  12.0   8.0   25.0   40.0   8.0
2.0   3.0   4.0   3.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   3.0  24.0  60.0  48.0  24.0   75.0  120.0  32.0
3.0   4.0   2.0   1.0   5.0   4.0   1.0   2.0 120.0 180.0  96.0 144.0  375.0  240.0  96.0
4.0   5.0   4.0   2.0   2.0   5.0   5.0   2.0 720.0 900.0 288.0 432.0 2250.0 1440.0 288.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I like the idea of pairs too! very impressive!